# Exercise 7.1 of From Calculus To Cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The book can be found [here](https://archive.org/details/MadsenI.H.TornehaveJ.FromCalculusToCohomologyDeRhamCohomologyAndCharacteristicClasses1996).

The exercise asks the following:

> Show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not contain any subset homeomorphic to $D^m$ with $m>n$, where $D^m$ is the $m$-dimensional ball.

First of all, if I call $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ a set which I'm going to assume is homeomorphic to $D^m$ via $\phi$, then $A$ is compact and connected. In particular $A$ is closed.

The case when $n=1$ is easy, because the connected compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the closed and bounded intervals, which are easily shown not to be homeomorphic to $D^m$ for $m>1$.

For the general case, from lemma 7.6, I know that there exists a homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ such that $h(x,0_m)=(0_n,\phi(x))$ for all $x\in A$. Hence, I can consider $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}-A$ identifying $A$ with $A\times \{0_m\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}-D^m$ identifying $D^m$ with $h(A, 0_m)=(0_n,\phi(A))=(0_n,D^m)$. And what's more, these sets are homeomorphic.

From this point, I was thinking about using the cohomology of this two subspaces, which should be identical, and come to a contradiction, but I can't find the way.

---

Is this a right way to face this problem? In that case, how could I continue? If not, what would be a more straightforward way to solve it? I also thought about using invariance of domain, but I didn't know how.

**Note:** I'm only supposed to use the deRham cohomology of open euclidean spaces.

Comment: Invariance of domain is how it's done. Using the cohomology of the two spaces does not work by itself, but by looking into the proof of invariance of domain you will discover which (co)homology groups do work.

Comment: @LeeMosher I should find homeomorphic open sets $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$. The only open sets I've got are $\mathbb{R}^n-A$ and $\mathbb{R}^m-D^m$, but I cannot say that they're homeomorphic.

Comment: Again, you'll see in the proof of invariance of domain what kind of (co)homology works. It's not "absolute" homology that one uses, but instead "relative" homology. My best suggestion is you go find out how invariance of domain is proved.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think Madsen does a different proof from what you're thinking of, because he doesn't use relative homology.

Comment: Hint: if you remove a point from the interior of an $n$ ball, it has the cohomology of an $n-1$ sphere.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Madsen only talks in his book about the cohomology of open euclidean spaces. Thus I think I shouldn't use that fact.

Comment: Well, does it calculate the cohomology of a ball minus an interior point?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip he does calculate the cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus any finite number of points. So I can use that, and any other open and homotopy equivalent space.

Comment: That's going to be crucial for your calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier. If $A$ is homeomorphic to $D^m$ then their interiors are homeomorphic too. Hence, one would have an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (the interior of $A$) homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (the interior of the ball), which is not possible by the invariance of domain.